# Ruby self.name or @name

Tags: ruby

I have a question about what the best way is to reference a class variable in Ruby.

Here is a class I made:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def say_name
    puts @name
  end

  def say_name2
    puts self.name
  end

end

bob = Person.new("Bob")

bob.say_name 
=> "Bob"

bob.say_name2
=> "Bob"
```

Both of the "say_name" methods seems to work as intended. Why use the @variable vs the self.variable??

Comment: You don't even need the `self.` in your second method, unless you're assigning, it can just be `name`...

Comment: You don't have any class variable in your code above.

Answer (score 3):

`attr_accessor :name` just creates method `name`, which returns `@name` variable, something like

```
def name
  @name
end
```

instead of you.

Without `attr_accessor` both `self.name` and `name` will not work and return `NoMethodError`.
`@name` will work in all cases.